# Is it possible to send nested structure using MPI_Datatype in MPI using C

Tags: c, algorithm, mpi, distributed-computing

I have a structure :

```
    struct vertex
    {
     double a; double b;
    }

    struct polygon
    {
     int numofVertex;
     vertex v[10];
    }
```

How to send this nested structure in MPI using MPI_Send?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your structure does not contain any pointers, it's easily possible.

```
MPI_Send(ptr_to_your_struct, sizeof(struct polygon), MPI_BYTES, ...);
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, I think the sent structure can be easily accessed by MPI_Recv(ptr_to_struct, sizeof(struct polygon), MPI_BYTES, ...);

Comment: Can you provide some insight when the structure contains pointer fields. Moreover, I have asked this problem as a new question.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5972018/how-to-sendmpi-send-nested-structure-having-pointer-fields-in-mpi-using-c