# How to send(MPI_Send) nested structure having pointer fields in MPI using C

Tags: c, serialization, mpi, distributed-computing

I have a structure :

```
    struct vertex 
    {  
     double a; double b;
    }      

    struct polygon
    {
     int numofVertex;
     vertex *v;
    }
```

How to send this nested structure in MPI using MPI_Send?
The problem is that the structure contains pointer field "v" due to which MPI_Send crashes.
I have tried MPI_Datatype to define new data type, it doesnot work. 
I read that serialization is the only solution but C doesnot provide such implementation.
Any suggestions how to get around with this problem?

Comment: You're right that C doesn't provide an implementation to serialize arbitrary structures.  What's stopping you from writing one for these structures?

Comment: @Carl I think it is difficult to do so, and in case there is some existing implementation, I dont want to reinvent the wheel. @CarlNorum

Comment: I think you're going to have to write it... it shouldn't be that hard.  Please come back and ask a specific question if you have a problem with your implementation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll have to send it in two messages:

```
// 'p' is a pointer to your polygon
vertex *tmp = p->v;
p->v = NULL;
MPI_Send(p, sizeof(struct polygon), MPI_BYTES, dest, 1, ...);
MPI_Send(tmp, sizeof(struct vertex), MPI_BYTES, dest, 2, ...);
p->v = tmp;
```

On the receiving end, you simply receive the struct in two steps:

```
polygon p;
MPI_Recv(&p, sizeof(struct polygon), MPI_BYTES, src, 1, ...);
p.vertex = malloc(sizeof(struct vertex));
MPI_Recv(p.vertex, sizeof(struct vertex), MPI_BYTES, src, 2, ...);
```

Obviously this is not very nice, so it'll be easier if you keep your struct pointer-less so you can send it at once.