# How to send nested structures in MPI using MPI_Send

Tags: c++, mpi

I need to send  the plista array using MPI_SEND :

```
Traza* plista;

    struct Evento{
    char* evento;
    unsigned char cant;
    };

    struct Traza
    {
            char* nombre;
            Evento* eventos;
        unsigned int cantEventos;
            bool revisado;
            unsigned int idTraza;
    };
```

I read some articles in the witch the peoples use MPI_PACKED, but this is a complicated structure.

Comment: You can't send it as a single structure. You will have to send two structures separately. Check  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5972018/how-to-sendmpi-send-nested-structure-having-pointer-fields-in-mpi-using-c?rq=1

Comment: I tried that option, but in that post just use a unique estructure, and I use an array of structures of Traza. Besides, i dont know how works that exactly, because in the post send using sizeof just over the structure and I send a list of structures of type Evento

Comment: Since you have an array of elements you will have to iterate over it and send as a loop. The user has suggested sizeof() because the structure is serialized to bytes and sent. Your other option is to declare your own `MPI_Datatype` and then send the structure.

Comment: Thanks  Pooja Nilangekar, i have read something about MPI_Datatype, but i have not a clear idea of how to do it, can you help me to do it with this complicated structure, because I am new in MPI, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data structure you want to send is complicated in the sense that it contains pointers to substructures.  Communicating the pointers obviously does not make sense, instead you have to recourse into the substructures in the style of a deep copy.  Additionally some of the substructures contain arrays of dynamic length, known only to the sender beforehand, so the receiver is unable to allocate the correct amount of memory.

You may be tempted to create your own composite MPI data types, and indeed it is possible to do so by making use of `MPI_BOTTOM` and encoding the absolute addresses of all of the sub-parts of the data structure.  You need to create this custom data type anew each time you want to do a communication, since you are likely to use different data and thus the absolute addresses change.  However, *this only works on the sender side*, since on the receiver you still do not know how much memory to allocate for each part of your data structure.

One way to solve this is to do many communications, sending the sizes first and then the data separately.  This however has the disadvantage of increasing the number of communications and can introduce unnecessary latencies.

Enter `MPI_PACKED`, which you already mentioned.  `MPI_PACKED` lets you pack the data you want to send one piece at a time into a buffer, and then sending the whole buffer in a single communication.  On the receiving side, it can be received in a single communication, and then unpacked piece by piece.

Below is a solution for your data structure that uses `MPI_PACKED`.

**Note:** I know pretty much nothing about latin languages, so I had to make guesses what some of your identifiers mean.  Namely I interpreted

- `cant` as an element count of some kind
- `Evento::evento` as an array of numbers that happen to fit into a `char`, with the length of the array in `Evento::cant`.
- `Traza::nombre` as an array of numbers and `Traza::eventos` as an array of events, with the length for both arrays given by `Traza::cantEventos`

It should be easy to correct these interpretations where they are incorrect (just obtain the sizes of the arrays from the correct source and pack them up separately the way I packed up the number of `Traza` in the message).

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <vector>

#include <mpi.h>

struct Evento {
  char* evento;
  unsigned char cant;
};

struct Traza
{
  char* nombre;
  Evento* eventos;
  unsigned int cantEventos;
  bool revisado;
  unsigned int idTraza;
};

void pack_plista(int incount, Traza* data, MPI_Comm comm,
                 std::vector<char> &buf)
{
  int pos = 0;
  buf.clear();
  int size;

  MPI_Pack_size(1, MPI_INT, comm, &size);
  buf.resize(pos+size);
  MPI_Pack(&incount, 1, MPI_INT, buf.data(), buf.size(), &pos, comm);

  for(int t = 0; t < incount; ++t)
  {
    MPI_Pack_size(2, MPI_UNSIGNED, comm, &size);
    buf.resize(pos+size);
    MPI_Pack(&data[t].cantEventos, 1, MPI_UNSIGNED,
             buf.data(), buf.size(), &pos, comm);
    MPI_Pack(&data[t].idTraza, 1, MPI_UNSIGNED,
             buf.data(), buf.size(), &pos, comm);

    MPI_Pack_size(1, MPI_UNSIGNED_CHAR, comm, &size);
    buf.resize(pos+size);
    { // MPI does not know about C++ bool
      unsigned char revisado = data[t].revisado;
      MPI_Pack(&revisado, 1, MPI_UNSIGNED_CHAR,
               buf.data(), buf.size(), &pos, comm);
    }

    // This interprets Traza::nombre as a character code, which is probably incorrect
    // However, that is unlikely to be a problem, unless you are in a
    // heterogeneous ASCII/EBCDIC environment
    MPI_Pack_size(data[t].cantEventos, MPI_CHAR, comm, &size);
    buf.resize(pos+size);
    MPI_Pack(data[t].nombre, data[t].cantEventos, MPI_CHAR,
             buf.data(), buf.size(), &pos, comm);

    for(unsigned int e = 0; e < data[t].cantEventos; ++e)
    {
      // send count (interpret as a number)
      MPI_Pack_size(1, MPI_UNSIGNED_CHAR, comm, &size);
      buf.resize(pos+size);
      MPI_Pack(&data[t].eventos[e].cant, 1, MPI_UNSIGNED_CHAR,
               buf.data(), buf.size(), &pos, comm);

      // send events (interpret as character codes)
      MPI_Pack_size(data[t].eventos[e].cant, MPI_CHAR, comm, &size);
      buf.resize(pos+size);
      MPI_Pack(data[t].eventos[e].evento, data[t].eventos[e].cant, MPI_CHAR,
               buf.data(), buf.size(), &pos, comm);
    }
  }
  buf.resize(pos);
}

void unpack_plista(int &outcount, Traza* &data, MPI_Comm comm,
                   // buf cannot be reference-to-const since MPI_Unpack takes
                   // pointer-to-nonconst
                   std::vector<char> &buf)
{
  int pos = 0;

  MPI_Unpack(buf.data(), buf.size(), &pos, &outcount, 1, MPI_INT, comm);

  data = new Traza[outcount];
  for(int t = 0; t < outcount; ++t)
  {
    MPI_Unpack(buf.data(), buf.size(), &pos,
               &data[t].cantEventos, 1, MPI_UNSIGNED, comm);
    MPI_Unpack(buf.data(), buf.size(), &pos,
               &data[t].idTraza, 1, MPI_UNSIGNED, comm);

    { // MPI does not know about C++ bool
      unsigned char revisado;
      MPI_Unpack(buf.data(), buf.size(), &pos,
                 &revisado, 1, MPI_UNSIGNED_CHAR, comm);
      data[t].revisado = revisado;
    }

    // This interprets Traza::nombre as a character code, which is probably incorrect
    // However, that is unlikely to be a problem, unless you are in a
    // heterogeneous ASCII/EBCDIC environment
    data[t].nombre = new char[data[t].cantEventos];
    MPI_Unpack(buf.data(), buf.size(), &pos,
               data[t].nombre, data[t].cantEventos, MPI_CHAR, comm);

    data[t].eventos = new Evento[data[t].cantEventos];
    for(unsigned int e = 0; e < data[t].cantEventos; ++e)
    {
      // receive count (interpret as a number)
      MPI_Unpack(buf.data(), buf.size(), &pos,
                 &data[t].eventos[e].cant, 1, MPI_UNSIGNED_CHAR, comm);

      // receive events (interpret as character codes)
      data[t].eventos[e].evento = new char[data[t].eventos[e].cant];
      MPI_Unpack(buf.data(), buf.size(), &pos,
                 data[t].eventos[e].evento, data[t].eventos[e].cant, MPI_CHAR,
                 comm);
    }
  }
}

void send_plista(int incount, Traza* data, int dest, int tag, MPI_Comm comm)
{
  std::vector<char> buf;
  pack_plista(incount, data, comm, buf);
  MPI_Send(buf.data(), buf.size(), MPI_PACKED, dest, tag, comm);
}

void recv_plista(int &outcount, Traza* &data,
                 int src, int tag, MPI_Comm comm)
{
  MPI_Status status;
  MPI_Probe(src, tag, comm, &status);
  int size;
  MPI_Get_count(&status, MPI_PACKED, &size);
  std::vector<char> buf(size);
  MPI_Recv(buf.data(), buf.size(), MPI_PACKED, src, tag, comm, &status);

  unpack_plista(outcount, data, comm, buf);
}

void make_test_data(int &count, Traza *&data) {
  count = 2;
  data = new Traza[2] {
    {
      new char[3] { char(0), char(1), char(3) },
      new Evento[3] {
        {
          new char[4] { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' },
          (unsigned char)4,
        },
        {
          new char[3] { 'e', 'f', 'g' },
          (unsigned char)3,
        },
        {
          new char[2] { 'h', 'i' },
          (unsigned char)2,
        },
      },
      3u,
      true,
      0u,
    },
    {
      new char[1] { char(4) },
      new Evento[1] {
        {
          new char[1] { 'j' },
          (unsigned char)1,
        },
      },
      1u,
      false,
      1u,
    },
  };
}

void print_data(std::ostream &out, int count, const Traza *data)
{
  for(int t = 0; t < count; ++t)
  {
    std::cout << "{\n"
              << "  nombre = { ";
    for(unsigned e = 0; e < data[t].cantEventos; ++e)
      std::cout << int(data[t].nombre[e]) << ", ";
    std::cout << "},\n"
              << "  eventos = {\n";
    for(unsigned e = 0; e < data[t].cantEventos; ++e)
    {
      std::cout << "    {\n"
                << "      evento = { ";
      for(int c = 0; c < data[t].eventos[e].cant; ++c)
        std::cout << "'" << data[t].eventos[e].evento[c] << "', ";
      std::cout << "},\n"
                << "      cant = " << int(data[t].eventos[e].cant) << ",\n"
                << "    },\n";
    }
    std::cout << "  },\n"
              << "  cantEventos = " << data[t].cantEventos << ",\n"
              << "  revisado = " << data[t].revisado << ",\n"
              << "  idTraza = " << data[t].idTraza << ",\n"
              << "}," << std::endl;
  }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int rank;
  Traza *plista = nullptr;
  int count = 0;

  MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
  if(rank == 1) {
    make_test_data(count, plista);
    send_plista(count, plista, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  }
  else if(rank == 0) {
    recv_plista(count, plista, 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    print_data(std::cout, count, plista);
  }
  // don't bother freeing allocated memory, the process is ending anyway
  MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Sample run:

```
-*- mode: compilation; default-directory: "/tmp/" -*-
Compilation started at Wed Sep  9 20:04:24

set -ex; mpic++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wno-literal-suffix -o check check.cc; mpirun -n 2 ./check
+ mpic++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wno-literal-suffix -o check check.cc
+ mpirun -n 2 ./check
{
  nombre = { 0, 1, 3, },
  eventos = {
    {
      evento = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', },
      cant = 4,
    },
    {
      evento = { 'e', 'f', 'g', },
      cant = 3,
    },
    {
      evento = { 'h', 'i', },
      cant = 2,
    },
  },
  cantEventos = 3,
  revisado = true,
  idTraza = 0,
},
{
  nombre = { 4, },
  eventos = {
    {
      evento = { 'j', },
      cant = 1,
    },
  },
  cantEventos = 1,
  revisado = false,
  idTraza = 1,
},

Compilation finished at Wed Sep  9 20:04:26
```

Comment: Thanks ex-bart, i will try  your suggestion, thank you very much for spend your time on me, thanks a lot.